# Magento 2: How to check the localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage') value is empty?

Tags: magento2, cache, local-storage

How to check if the `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')` is empty in Magento 2?

It is returning {}.

Please guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem` returns a string. You could something like this

```
let localStorage = localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage');
if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && localStorage !== '{}') {
    // Your mage cache storage isn't empty
}
```

if there is something in it and you want to use it then add to this code

```
else {
    // mage cache storage is populated
    let data = JSON.parse(localStorage);
    console.log(data.cart.subtotalAmount); // or whatever...
}
```

Comment: how to check if $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')).wishlist => here if wishlist is defined or not

Comment: @Arjun you can check the type of `wishlist` key. Expanding on my example above: `typeof data.wishlist === 'object'`